Upper bound for $ \prod_{i=0}^{k^2} \left(1 + \frac{n-1}{k+(n-1)i}\right) \left(1 - \frac{1}{k+(n-1)i}\right)^{n-1}$
I am working on finding a good upper bound for the following product:
$ \prod_{i=0}^{k^2} \left(1 + \frac{n-1}{k+(n-1)i}\right) \left(1 - \frac{1}{k+(n-1)i}\right)^{n-1} $
With the following constraints: $k \geq n$ and $n \geq 2$.
Here is my attempt at the solution:
To simplify the expression, I will analyze the factors separately:

Consider the first factor:
$ 1 + \frac{n-1}{k+(n-1)i} $
Since $ \frac{n-1}{k+(n-1)i} $ is positive, the term $ 1 + \frac{n-1}{k+(n-1)i} $ is always greater than or equal to 1.

Now, consider the second factor:
$ \left(1 - \frac{1}{k+(n-1)i}\right)^{n-1} $
For $ k + (n-1)i $ large enough, the term $ \frac{1}{k+(n-1)i} $ is small, making $ 1 - \frac{1}{k+(n-1)i} $ close to 1. Using the approximation $ (1 - x)^{n-1} \approx e^{-(n-1)x} $ for small $ x $, we get:
$ \left(1 - \frac{1}{k+(n-1)i}\right)^{n-1} \approx e^{-\frac{n-1}{k+(n-1)i}} $


Putting these together, the product can be approximated by:
$ \prod_{i=0}^{k^2} \left(1 + \frac{n-1}{k+(n-1)i}\right) \cdot e^{-\frac{n-1}{k+(n-1)i}} $
Next, I observe that:
$ \left(1 + \frac{n-1}{k+(n-1)i}\right) \leq e^{\frac{n-1}{k+(n-1)i}} $
Thus, the product can be bounded above by:
$ \prod_{i=0}^{k^2} e^{\frac{n-1}{k+(n-1)i}} \cdot e^{-\frac{n-1}{k+(n-1)i}} = 1 $
However, this seems too simplistic. Therefore, I think a more precise upper bound can be obtained by considering finer approximations or other bounding techniques. Any insights or suggestions to refine this bound would be greatly appreciated.
Additionally, I wrote a Python program to compute this product for specific values of $ n $ and $ k $. Here is the code:
def compute_product(n, k):
    product = 1.0
    for i in range(k**2 + 1):
        term1 = 1 + (n - 1) / (k + (n - 1) * i)
        term2 = (1 - 1 / (k + (n - 1) * i)) ** (n - 1)
        product *= term1 * term2
    return product

# Get inputs from the user
n = int(input("Enter the value of n: "))
k = int(input("Enter the value of k: "))

# Compute the product
result = compute_product(n, k)

# Print the result
print(f"The computed product is: {result}")

# Example computation for n=10 and k=100
example_result = compute_product(10, 100)
print(f"Example result for n=10 and k=100: {example_result} (Expected: ~0.95)")

When I run this program with $ n = 10 $ and $ k = 100 $, I get a result of approximately 0.95.

Try to work the next term; for the test case, I got $\frac{17107}{18000}=0.950389$

For more simplicity, define
$$a_i=(n-1)i+(k+n-1)$$ $$b_i=(n-1)i+k$$
$$c_i=   (n-1)i+(k-1) $$ to face
$$A_k=\Bigg(\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{k^2} a_i}{\prod_{i=0}^{k^2} b_i}\Bigg)\, \Bigg(\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{k^2} c_i}{\prod_{i=0}^{k^2} b_i}\Bigg)^{n-1}$$
$$\prod_{i=0}^{k^2} a_i=(n-1)^{k^2+1}\,\,\frac{\Gamma \left(k^2+\frac{k}{n-1}+2\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{k+n-1}{n-1}\right)}$$
$$\prod_{i=0}^{k^2} b_i=(n-1)^{k^2+1}\,\,\frac{\Gamma \left(k^2+\frac{k}{n-1}+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{n-1}\right)}$$
$$\prod_{i=0}^{k^2} c_i=(n-1)^{k^2+1}\,\,\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{(n-1) k^2+k+n-2}{n-1}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{k-1}{n-1}\right)}$$ Take logarithms,use Stirling approximation, polish with Taylor series
$$\log(A)=-\frac{n}{2 k}-\frac{n \left(n^2-7\right)}{12 (n-1) k^2}-\frac{n
   \left(n^3-2 n^2+n+6\right)}{12
   (n-1)^2 k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$$
Now, Taylor
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=1-\frac{n}{2 k}+\frac{n \left(n^2-3 n+14\right)}{24  (n-1)\,k^2}+$$ $$\frac{n \left(n^4-4 n^3-7 n^2+10 n-24\right)}{48  (n-1)^2\,k^3}+o\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)$$
For your test case $(n=10,k=100)$, converted to decimals. $\color{red}{0.95040}27$.
